# Akka Stream, Tcp().bind, handle when the client close the socket

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, tcpsocket, akka-io

I'm quite new in Akka Stream and I'd like to learn how handle a TCP socket for a project of mine. I took this piece of code from the [Akka Stream official documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html).

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing

val connections: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] =
  Tcp().bind(host, port)

connections.runForeach { connection =>
  println(s"New connection from: ${connection.remoteAddress}")

  val echo = Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .map(_ + "!!!\n")
    .map(ByteString(_))

  connection.handleWith(echo)
}
```

If I connect from the terminal using netcat I can see that the Akka Stream TCP socket works as expected. I also found out that If I need to close the connection using an user message, I can use a `takeWhile` as follow

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing

val connections: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] =
  Tcp().bind(host, port)

connections.runForeach { connection =>
  println(s"New connection from: ${connection.remoteAddress}")

  val echo = Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .takeWhile(_.toLowerCase.trim != "exit")   // < - - - - - - HERE
    .map(_ + "!!!\n")
    .map(ByteString(_))

  connection.handleWith(echo)
}
```

What I can't find is how to manage a socket closed by a `CMD + C` action. Akka Stream use Akka.io to manage the TCP connection internally, so it must send some of its `PeerClose` messages when the socket is closed. So, my understanding of Akka.io tells me that I should receive a feedback from the socket closing but I can't find how to do that with Akka Stream. Is there a way to manage that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connection.handleWith(echo)` is syntactic sugar for `connection.flow.joinMat(echo)(Keep.right).run()` which will have the materialized value of `echo`, which is generally not useful.  `Flow.via.map.takeWhile` has `NotUsed` as a materialized value, so that's also basically useless.  However, you can attach stages to `echo` which will materialize differently.

One of these is `.watchTermination`:

```
connections.runForeach { connection =>
  println(s"New connection from: ${connection.remoteAddress}")

  val echo: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, Future[Done]] = Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .takeWhile(_.toLowerCase.trim != "exit")   // < - - - - - - HERE
    .map(_ + "!!!\n")
    .map(ByteString(_))
    // change the materialized value to a Future[Done]
    .watchTermination()(Keep.right)

  // you may need to have an implicit ExecutionContext in scope, e.g. system.dispatcher,
  //  if you don't already
  connection.handleWith(echo).onComplete {
    case Success(_) => println("stream completed successfully")
    case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
  }
}
```

This will not distinguish between your side or the remote side closing the connection normally; it will distinguish the stream failing.